# Convert .blf to mdf or mf4 in Python

Tags: python, vector, mdf, python-can, asammdf

I want to convert .blf files to mdf or mf4 format.
The .blf is recorded over multiple channels
multiple .dbc are to be used to decode the signals

So far i found different modules to work with CAN data (asammdf, python-can, mdfreader,canmatrix) and partial code examples on SO and Google but I still can't figure out how to make it work.